# R: Finding relationships between 2 variables to determine any patterns in data

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, pattern-recognition

I am working on finding relationships/patterns between 2 variables (Type_A, Type_B).

```
Loc_ID <- c("45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51")
Type_A <- c(22.96,23.36,23.70,23.55,23.52,23.42,23.61)
Type_B <- c(9.26,9.28,9.35,9.44,9.42,9.43,9.46)

df1 <- data.frame(Loc_ID,Type_A,Type_B)
```

**df1:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Loc_ID | Type_A | Type_B |
+--------+--------+--------+
|     45 | 22.96  | 9.26   |
|     46 | 23.36  | 9.28   |
|     47 | 23.70  | 9.35   |
|     48 | 23.55  | 9.44   |
|     49 | 23.52  | 9.42   |
|     50 | 23.42  | 9.43   |
|     51 | 23.61  | 9.46   |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Loc_ID is the location ID. Type_A & Type_B are 2 different measurement types.

**Some Background:** 
This data was gathered from an experiment studying different hard discs. There are some hard discs that failed and some that passed. I determine this metric based on just looking at some contour profile plots of the discs using the measurement types I mentioned above. This is not an efficient process and I want to apply some data mining or machine learning techniques to automate my tasks. I did some extensive feature selection and I am sure that these measurement types tell me something about the potential causes in the process. I want to know how data mining could help determine the failure at the early stage and eliminate it.

**Note:** I have reported a fraction of the data for one of the failed disc here in the example.

I have tried the following so far

1. Generated simple stats and plots for initial visualization
2. Calculate key features of the data by performing dimensionality reduction
3. Found correlations in the dataset to determine if any relationships.

I would like to know any other methods to efficiently carry out this relationship analysis of these 2 measurement types. For example: profile comparisons with respect to locations, predict both the measurement types for building better models. I am just not able to think of best practices in machine learning to handle this problem. Kindly let me know any other techniques and how I could tackle this? I would like to automate my analysis so that I could use it on all the bad and good discs.

Answer (score 1):

Although you gave some data it is still hard to tell what would be the best method to use for your challenge. Still I give it a shot.

In general it is always a good idea to do the steps you did already: summary statistics, visualization, correlation, linear regression.

In case the functional form doesn't seem to be linear you could try to find some other functional form. A good package is the following:

[rgp: R genetic programming framework](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp/index.html)

> RGP is a simple modular Genetic Programming (GP) system build in pure
>   R. In addition to general GP tasks, the system supports Symbolic
>   Regression by GP through the familiar R model formula interface. GP
>   individuals are represented as R expressions, an (optional) type
>   system enables domain-specific function sets containing functions of
>   diverse domain- and range types. A basic set of genetic operators for
>   variation (mutation and crossover) and selection is provided.

The vignette can be found [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Frgp%2Fvignettes%2Frgp_introduction.pdf&ei=lrM3Va3eNoacygOGlIDQCA&usg=AFQjCNE6-klZM2ch_ngHq5NDKwDAqtfdxA&sig2=dnGTMc-BVPInYcV5aoLpfQ&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGQ)

To give you a code example based on your data:

```
library(rgp)

Loc_ID <- c("45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51")
Type_A <- c(22.96,23.36,23.70,23.55,23.52,23.42,23.61)
Type_B <- c(9.26,9.28,9.35,9.44,9.42,9.43,9.46)

df1 <- data.frame(Loc_ID,Type_A,Type_B)

iter <- 1000
set.seed(123)
newFuncSet <- functionSet("+","*","-","/","sin","cos")

result1 <- symbolicRegression(Type_B ~ Type_A, data=df1, functionSet=newFuncSet, stopCondition=makeStepsStopCondition(iter))
#result1 <- symbolicRegression(Type_B ~ Type_A, data=df1, functionSet=newFuncSet, stopCondition=makeFitnessStopCondition(0.1))

plot(df1$Type_B, col=1, type="l"); points(predict(result1, newdata = df1), col=2, type="l")
    #The best and worst individual can be shown using these commands:
    bf <- result1$population[[which.min(sapply(result1$population, result1$fitnessFunction))]]
bf
```

The results are not very meaningful for this very small dataset but you should give it a try with the real dataset. You should fiddle a little with the function set and with the number of iterations (`iter`) to see if you get better fitting results.

I would be interested if you get any interesting results. This is only one possibility how to proceed but I hope it helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks @vonjd for your response. I ran your code but I am getting this error in point(predict()) function. Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Type_A' not found . How do I get rid of this?

Comment: @Sharath: This is strange, I removed all objects and ran it again: No error! Did you just copy and paste it, installed the rgp package and ran the code? Please run it first with my code above before you test it on your bigger data-frame. Perhaps there is some error in this data-frame. Otherwise I have no idea...

Comment: @vonjid, I just pasted your code and ran it. When I run result1 line, It now says "Error in is.empty(conset$all) : object 'numericConstantSet' not found"

Comment: @Sharath: I tried the above code on a different computer - and it worked alright! So there must be a problem with your R installation.

Comment: Works now!! Thanks. But when I use the points function, I don't see it on the plot. How does the points function work?. What are you getting in your computer? Also, Could you please explain me what  the "bf" line does? I get an output "function (Type_A) 9.38031238503754" but I am not able to interpret what it means. Please help on this.

Comment: @Sharath: As I said, the result is not very meaningful because there are not enough data. You get a constant as the resulting function (basically something like a weighted average). Did you try it with more data?

Comment: I tried it on more data. I get a constant as the output and it is something like "Type_A * 0.420695958687057"